# Completely remove casting ability from PC to TV

Tags: google-chrome, chromecast

I am using Chrome browser. Every time I watch a youtube video I get a cast icon in the video navigation.
Every time I right click somewhere on any site I get a casting tab option.

How do I stop this from happening ? I dont want clicking it on accident and showing what I watch or listen to everyone else in the house...

I have tried all "about config" options I could find on the net, but they do not work on the newest versions of chrome or are entirely missing. I just want to not have this casting option at all on my computer.
Is there any way to cripple it or remove it entirely either through the pc or the router ?

Comment: Try this : Open `chrome://flags/` in Chrome, type `cast` in the search field and disable every related option. Restart Chrome.

Comment: It doesnt work.

Comment: Try to disable `chrome://flags/#allow-all-sites-to-initiate-mirroring`.

Comment: It also doesnt work. I have disabled everything in there related to cast and it has no effect. I have noticed chrome disabling the functionalities of their flag booleans in the newer versions. Those flags related to casting probably work on some older version, but they do not on the latest one.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like disabling casting cannot be done any more.

The option that controlled it was called "Cast Media Route Provider" in
`chrome://flags`, but it has disappeared.

As all other options relating to "cast" were disabled without effect,
there is no other known method for disabling it.

The only action possible is to post in the Chrome forums a request for
this, as feature request.

Comment: I am not giving up just yet. The pc and tv are finding each other because they are all linked to a single network. So there must be a way to break this connection just for my PC. I have found a promising lead on my rauter but cant test it at the moment. Will write later with a follow-up.

Comment: If the router has a firewall, it may be able to do that.

Comment: ok I switched to a guest network in my rauter. This disconnected me from the home network while I still had internet. So chrome or anything else on my pc couldn't cast to anyone else. But my rauter settings severely limited me in other ways and there weren't any options to change that... So I am back to square 1

Comment: You could use instead Microsoft Edge, which is Chromium-based, but there casting is done via the three-dot menu "More tools", so is harder to get to.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a way to do this in Chrome settings but I achieved the same outcome by adding an outbound rule to block all local IP addresses except for the router to the Windows Firewall. Of course you can also simply block the device you are casting to if you know its IP address to not lose access to your other local devices. The outbound rule looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ch9gA.png) in my case.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I tried that, but when blocking all local IPs, I still can detect the TV in the living room... I dont really understand how is that possible... When blocking both local and remote, then I dont have any internet at all. So the rule does work for remote IPs at least.. Do you have any ideas why it doesn't work for local ones ?

Comment: One explanation that comes to my mind is that you are also including your router in the address range when you block all local IP addresses, which causes your PC to not be able to reach the router, which in turn cuts your internet connection. Check the default gateway IP address (which is usually the routers IP) and exclude it from the blocked IP range and see if it works then. Also make sure that the rule is outbound and not inbound. (And also you shouldn't have to add anything to the local IP address box of the rule, you can leave it empty just like in the screenshot.)